# 'NoneType' is not iterable while recursively parsing a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, data-structures

With this function:

```
def extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c = []):
    for i in ['left', 'op', 'right', 'func', 'value', 'args', 
              'ctx', 'body', 'comparators', 'ops', 'test', 'orelse', 'targets', 'slice']:
        if i in nested_dict:
            if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
                for b in nested_dict[i]:
                    yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']]) 
            else:
                yield from extract_flat_branch(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']]) 
    lis = [c+[nested_dict['_type'], i] for i in filter(None, [nested_dict.get(j) for j in ['n', 'id']])]
    yield from lis if lis else [c+[nested_dict['_type']]] if len(nested_dict) == 1 else []
```

I am traversing and extracting the branches of this tree represented as this dictionary ([my_dict](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YCq2NX5VFn/)), as a list of strings where all the branches of the tree are elements of a flat list. However, for some reason when I do:

In:

```
print(list(extract_flat_branch(my_dict)))
```

Instead of getting an output similar like this:

```
[[node_1, node_2, .., node_n],[node_1, node_2, .., node_n],...,[node_1, node_2, .., node_n]]
```

I am getting:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Based on this [blog](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/beware-of-python-dict-get-98d7ffe6667e/), I thought that the problem was the `.get(j)` that I am using. However, if I do `nested_dict.get(j) or {} for j in ['n', 'id']])` I am still getting the same `TypeError`. Any idea of how to fix this issue and get a flat list of the branches of the tree?

This is the **full trace**:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-51bfd7bbf4e4> in <module>
      1 for i,j in enumerate(a_lis):
      2     print(i)
----> 3     print(list(extract_flat_branch(j)))

~/dir/util.py in extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c)
     38             if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
     39                 for b in nested_dict[i]:
---> 40                     yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']])
     41             else:
     42                 yield from extract_flat_branch(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']])

~/dir/util.py in extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c)
     38             if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
     39                 for b in nested_dict[i]:
---> 40                     yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']])
     41             else:
     42                 yield from extract_flat_branch(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']])

~/dir/util.py in extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c)
     40                     yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']])
     41             else:
---> 42                 yield from extract_flat_branch(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']])
     43     lis = [c+[nested_dict['_type'], i] for i in filter(None, [nested_dict.get(j) for j in ['n', 'id']])]
     44     yield from lis if lis else [c+[nested_dict['_type']]] if len(nested_dict) == 1 else []

~/dir/util.py in extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c)
     38             if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
     39                 for b in nested_dict[i]:
---> 40                     yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']])
     41             else:
     42                 yield from extract_flat_branch(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']])

~/dir/util.py in extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c)
     40                     yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']])
     41             else:
---> 42                 yield from extract_flat_branch(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']])
     43     lis = [c+[nested_dict['_type'], i] for i in filter(None, [nested_dict.get(j) for j in ['n', 'id']])]
     44     yield from lis if lis else [c+[nested_dict['_type']]] if len(nested_dict) == 1 else []

~/dir/util.py in extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c)
     35     for i in ['left', 'op', 'right', 'func', 'value', 'args', 
     36               'ctx', 'body', 'comparators', 'ops', 'test', 'orelse', 'targets', 'slice']:
---> 37         if i in nested_dict:
     38             if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
     39                 for b in nested_dict[i]:

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Comment: @00, I added the full trace, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NoneType` error is being raised because in your data there is a specific `"value"` key which is hashed to a corresponding `None`. `"value"` is a target key in the list of keys just below the function signature, and the current logic attempts to check if any such key exists in the function input `nested_dict`. It is rather unclear what your desired output is in the case of a target key with a `None` value, but a simple fix is to check and ignore such a case:

```
def extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c = []):
   for i in ['left', 'op', 'right', 'func', 'value', 'args', 'ctx', 'body', 'comparators', 'ops', 'test', 'orelse', 'targets', 'slice', 'n', 'id']:
      if i in nested_dict:
        if isinstance(nested_dict[i], list):
            for b in nested_dict[i]:
                yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[nested_dict['_type']]) 
        elif isinstance(nested_dict[i], dict): #simple check here
            yield from extract_flat_branch(nested_dict[i], c+[nested_dict['_type']]) 
        else:
            yield c+[nested_dict[i]]


print(list(extract_flat_branch(data)))
```

Output:

```
[['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Name', 'list'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Name', 'items'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Name', 'items'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Name', 'next_power_of_two'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'Name', 'int'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'BinOp', 'Num', 1.2], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'BinOp', 'Mult'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'len'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Call', 'Call', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'items'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Name', 'size'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'List', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Mult'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'size'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store'], ['FunctionDef', 'Assign', 'Name', 'table'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'hash_function'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Call', 'Name', 'i'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Mod'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'size'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Name', 'h'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Name', 's'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'AugAssign', 'Add'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'AugAssign', 'Num', 1], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'h'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'Add'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'BinOp', 'Name', 's'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Mod'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'BinOp', 'Name', 'size'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Store'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Assign', 'Name', 'h'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Compare', 'Subscript', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Compare', 'Subscript', 'Name', 'table'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Compare', 'Subscript', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Compare', 'Subscript', 'Index', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Compare', 'Subscript', 'Index', 'Name', 'h'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Compare', None], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'While', 'Compare', 'IsNot'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Name', 'i'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Subscript', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Subscript', 'Name', 'table'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Subscript', 'Store'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Subscript', 'Index', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'For', 'Assign', 'Subscript', 'Index', 'Name', 'h'], ['FunctionDef', 'Return', 'Name', 'Load'], ['FunctionDef', 'Return', 'Name', 'table']]
```

---

Updated solution:

```
def extract_flat_branch(nested_dict, c = []):
  targets = {'left', 'op', 'right', 'func', 'value', 'args', 'ctx', 'body', 'comparators', 'ops', 'test', 'orelse', 'targets', 'slice', 'n', 'id', 'slice', 'annotation', 'arg', 'elts', 's', '_type'}
  for a, b in nested_dict.items():
     if a in targets:
        if isinstance(b, dict):
           yield from extract_flat_branch(b, c+[a])
        elif isinstance(b, list):
           for i in b:
              yield from extract_flat_branch(i, c+[a])
        else:
            yield c+[b]

print(list(extract_flat_branch(data)))
```

Output:

```
[['FunctionDef'], ['args', 'arguments'], ['args', 'args', 'arg'], ['args', 'args', None], ['args', 'args', 'self'], ['body', 'Expr'], ['body', 'value', 'Str'], ['body', 'value', 'Like items(), but with all lowercase keys.'], ['body', 'Return'], ['body', 'value', 'GeneratorExp']]
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @JDo Glad to help!

Comment: Now I got: `TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable`. I tried to check as you do in this line: `elif nested_dict[i] is not None`. I changed it to: `elif nested_dict[i] is not None or bool` and it doesnt seem to work. How should I add that case?

Comment: @JDo if you first have a `None` and then a `bool` instead of an iterable, you should perhaps check whether `nested_dict[i]` is an iterable (but beware of strings). Then again, given that this happens more often, perhaps your code logic (or your input, but less likely) may need a more complete overhaul.

Comment: @JDo Please see my recent edit. Since it seems that target keys can store values of any type, I think the best way to approach this is simply to check if `nested_dict[i]` is an iterable.

Comment: @JDo I am not sure if the output is what you are looking for now but in this case, I added a line `yield c+[nested_dict[i]]` to generate the output lines in instances where the target key's value is not an iterable. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @JDo No problem, let me take a look

Comment: @JDo I updated the solution and I receive what appears to be correct when I run it on your latest input.

Comment: @JDo Thank you very much! Let me know if you need any additional help going forward.

Comment: @JDo No problem at all! Thank you very much!